# Tell pkg-config where to find packages on windows

Tags: windows, haskell, ffmpeg, pkg-config

I want to use the Haskell ffmpeg library under windows so I tried to install it via cabal. 
After downloading and extracting ffmpeg shared (64bit) version to C:\FFmpeg cabal complained that pkg-config was not installed. 
I downloaded it and moved it to the bin folder of MinGw. Now cabal complains that it can not find the pkg-config package libavutil.
First part of the question:
What is a pkg-config package? Is it just the dll that comes with the shared version of ffmpeg?
Second part:
I know pkg-config uses .pc files to describe where to look for packages and it uses the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to find .pc files. So how would a .pc file look when the libavutil dll is located in C:\FFmpeg\bin?

PS: The dll in FFmpeg\bin is named avutil-55.dll

Thanks

Comment: [see here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html)

Comment: @user2407038: OK this helped. But now cabal is complaining about missing c libraries: libavutil, libavformat, libavcodec, libswscale, libavdevice. I made a .pc file for every on of these. Then the error message says this: This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.